# How to use and share dropdown value tables across models using Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework-core, .net-core

I have tables consisting of an ID and a label that I use to populate dropdown lists throughout my project. In this example, I am using a list of cities:

```
public class Cities
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

I would like my Office model to reference the city list:

```
public class Office
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public int CityID { get; set; }
}
```

I know how to get my list of cities in my controller using something like this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    var office = await _context.Offices.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.OfficeID == id);
    var getCities = _context.Cities.ToList();
    ViewBag.citylist = new SelectList(getCities, "CityID", "CityName");
    return View(office);
}
```

Using the ViewBag doesn't seem like the elegant or proper way to populate the list, but it works.

If I create or update an office record, the city ID gets properly stored in the record I am updating. However, when I view the office record, I can only access the city ID. **I don't know how to access and display the city name using the city ID**. How can I access the city name from the Cities table using the cityID stored in the office record?

It would seem to be preferable to access all required information using something like this:

```
var offices = await _context.Offices
    --> .PseudoCode.GetTheCityNameFromTheID()  <---
    .ToListAsync();
```

But I don't know how to create and then use this kind of relationship (many-to-one?) between models, using Entity Framework Core. I know that I will only have one matching city value for each office record.

Also, what if I wanted to use the same city list to populate city information on other models, such as user profiles?

There are examples for pre-Core versions of EF, but the syntax doesn't seem to correlate to the newer Core syntax.

I have tried using data annotations such as `[ForeignKey("bar")]` and `[InverseProperty("foo")]`, but I am not sure this is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found the answer. In the model that will reference the dropdown list table, use a data annotation to set a `ForeignKey` attribute, and a `virtual` class:

```
public class Office
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Cities")]
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public virtual Cities cities { get; set; }
}
```

This will then allow the Office model to access values in the Cities model:

```
public class Cities
{
    public int CityID { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}
```

in your controller, like this:

```
var offices = await _context.Offices
    .Include(cityname => cityname.cities)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Then, in your view, you can display the city name associated with a record's city ID like this:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.cities.CityName)
```

At least this is working for me the way I expect it to. I still don't know if there's a more elegant way than `ViewBag` to get the contents of the cities table to populate a dropdown list, if anybody has a better way, I would love to know about it.

Comment: And an answer to whether ViewBag is the best way to pass the contents of a select list, according to the [ASP.net form documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/views/working-with-forms.html) :

"We do not recommend using ViewBag or ViewData with the Select Tag Helper. A view model is more robust at providing MVC metadata and generally less problematic."